# Google plus iOS API to pre-fill data in share is deprecated, what is the alternative

Tags: ios, google-plus

I have to share text, url and image in Google plus from iOS app. Google plus sign in is deprecated and only [basic sharing](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share) with text+url is available which is same as native iOS G + share. But I want to share image, url, etc., from my iOS app. Is any other way is possible to share media with text in Google plus now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google share link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink) supports two url paramaters: `url` for the target url, and `hl` for a language code.

```
- (void)showGooglePlusShare:(NSURL*)shareURL {

    // Construct the Google+ share URL
    NSURLComponents* urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc]
                             initWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/share"];
    urlComponents.queryItems = @[[[NSURLQueryItem alloc]
                                          initWithName:@"url"
                                          value:[shareURL absoluteString]]];
    NSURL* url = [urlComponents URL];

    if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
       // Open the URL in SFSafariViewController (iOS 9+)
       SFSafariViewController* controller = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]
                                                                 initWithURL:url];
       controller.delegate = self;
       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
      // Open the URL in the device's browser
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kurt Van den Branden Hello i had try above code, but it directly redirect me to google plus profile page, i try to paste same url in desktop browser, it shows me post window. Can you please help me out to solve issue.